# SonataUserBundle override form profile

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I am using SonataUserBundle and I am trying to override the edit profile form, but I am not sure about the services.yml and the config.yml. Here is the code.

ProfileType.php

```
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileType as BaseType;

class ProfileType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder->add('ciudad', null, array('label' => 'Ciudad'));
        $builder->add('file', 'file', array('required' => false, 'label' => 'Subir Foto'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'sonata_user_profile';
    }
}
```

ProfileFormHandler.php

```
<?php
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Handler;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Handler\ProfileFormHandler as BaseHandler;

class ProfileFormHandler extends BaseHandler
{
    public function process(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $this->form->setData($user);
        if ('POST' == $this->request->getMethod()) {
            $this->form->bindRequest($this->request);

            if ($this->form->isValid()) {
                 $nombreArchivoFoto = uniqid().$user->getId() . '-' . $user->getUsername() . '-foto-perfil.jpg';
                $user->upload($nombreArchivoFoto);
                $this->onSuccess($user);
                return true;
            }
            $this->userManager->reloadUser($user);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

services.yml

```
services:
    sonata_user.registration.form.type:
        class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: sonata_user_registration }

    sonata_user.profile.form.type:
        class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: sonata_user_profile }

    sonata_user.form.handler.profile:
        class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Handler\ProfileFormHandler
        arguments: ["@fos_user.profile.form", "@request", "@fos_user.user_manager"]
        scope: request
        public: false
```

Config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class:  Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
       form:
            type: application_sonata_user_registration
    profile:
       form:
            type:               fos_user_profile
            handler:            fos_user.profile.form.handler.default
            name:               fos_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Authentication]

sonata_user:
    security_acl:     false
    class:
        user:         Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
        group:        Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group

    profile:
        form:
            type:               sonata_user_profile
            handler:            sonata_user.form.handler.profile
            name:               sonata_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Profile]
```

If I use the above settings I get the next exception

> ErrorException: Runtime Notice: Declaration of
>   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Handler\ProfileFormHandler::process()
>   should be compatible with
>   Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Handler\ProfileFormHandler::process(FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface
>   $user) in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\misplanes.dev\src\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Handler\ProfileFormHandler.php
>   line 8

And if I change the services.yml

```
arguments: ["@sonata_user.profile.form", "@request", "@fos_user.user_manager"]
```

instead of

```
arguments: ["@fos_user.profile.form", "@request", "@fos_user.user_manager"]
```

I get the next exception

> ServiceNotFoundException: The service
>   "sonata.user.profile.form.handler" has a dependency on a non-existent
>   service "sonata_user.profile.form".

I don't really know where the mistake is, I have tried a lot of configurations and I have read different forums and blogs but I have not found the solution. I will really appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I finally have found the solution. In the code above I had various mistakes.

1. The ProfileType.php is ok, but I change the return parameter in the GetName() just to avoid conflicts, so, the code is here

   ```
   namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type;

   use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
   use Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileType as BaseType;
   use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

   class ProfileType extends BaseType
   {
       private $class;

       /**
        * @param string $class The User class name
        */
       public function __construct($class)
       {
           $this->class = $class;
       }
       public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
       {
           parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

           $builder->add('ciudad', null, array('label' => 'Ciudad'));
           $builder->add('file', 'file', array('required' => false, 'label' => 'Subir Foto'));
       }

       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
       public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
       {
           $resolver->setDefaults(array(
               'data_class' => $this->class
           ));
       }

       public function getName()
       {
           return 'application_sonata_user_profile';
       }
   }
   ```
2. ProfileFormHandler.php: I found a mistake here in the uses statement, so, the correct code is...

   ```
   use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
   use Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Handler\ProfileFormHandler as BaseHandler;

   class ProfileFormHandler extends BaseHandler 
   {

       public function process(UserInterface $user)
       {

           $this->form->setData($user);
           if ('POST' == $this->request->getMethod()) {
               $this->form->bindRequest($this->request);

               if ($this->form->isValid()) {
                   $nombreArchivoFoto = uniqid().$user->getId() . '-' . $user->getUsername() . '-foto-perfil.jpg';
                   $user->upload($nombreArchivoFoto);
                   $this->onSuccess($user);
                   return true;
               }
               $this->userManager->reloadUser($user);
           }
           return false;
       }

       protected function onSuccess(UserInterface $user)
       {
           $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Services.yml:

   ```
   services:
       sonata_user.registration.form.type:
           class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
           arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
           tags:
               - { name: form.type, alias: sonata_user_registration }

       sonata_user.profile.form.type:
           class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileType
           arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
           tags:
               - { name: form.type, alias: application_sonata_user_profile }

       sonata_user.form.handler.profile:
           class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Handler\ProfileFormHandler
           arguments: ["@sonata.user.profile.form", "@request", "@fos_user.user_manager"]
           scope: request
           public: false
   ```
4. Config.yml:

   ```
   fos_user:
       db_driver: orm
       firewall_name: main
       user_class:  Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
       registration:
           form:
               type: application_sonata_user_registration
       profile:
           form:
               type:               fos_user_profile
               handler:            fos_user.profile.form.handler.default
               name:               fos_user_profile_form
               validation_groups:  [Authentication]

   sonata_user:
       security_acl:     false
       class:
           user:         Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
           group:        Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group

       profile:  # Profile Form (firstname, lastname, etc ...)
           form:
               type:               application_sonata_user_profile
               handler:            sonata_user.form.handler.profile
               name:               sonata_user_profile_form
               validation_groups:  [Profile]
   ```

Finally, Another mistake was related with the template, I was using the `{{ form_rest(form) }}` to see the new fields, but I don't know why this didn't work, so I had to put the fields with:

```
{{ form_label(form.ciudad, 'CIUDAD') }}
{{ form_errors(form.ciudad) }}
{{ form_widget(form.ciudad) }}
```

PS. Sorry for my english level xD..

Comment: Thank you for posting this! It helped me figure out this process relatively painlessly.

Comment: My image is on onetoone , while error form submission. The image disappear from app.user .. current user session. while edit current user.