# Unable to override Sonata User Bundle registration form

Tags: forms, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I keep getting an error while trying to override sonata registration template.

I extended Sonata User Bundle with EasyExtendsBundle, so I now have src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle.

**EDIT:** Symfony 2.7, Sonata Admin 2.3, Sonata User dev-master

I added a field in my User Entity
**UserEntity.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * This file is part of the <name> project.
 *
 * (c) <yourname> <youremail>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;

/**
 * This file has been generated by the Sonata EasyExtends bundle ( http://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends )
 *
 * References :
 *   working with object : http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/working-with-objects/en
 *
 * @author <yourname> <youremail>
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    protected $id;

   /*
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     */
     protected $age;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

     public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->age;
    }

        public function setAge($age)
    {
         $this->age = $age;
    }
}
```

I then created a new RegisterForm
**Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Form/Type/RegisterType.php**

```
<?php

namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RegisterType extends RegistrationFormType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder
            ->add('age');
    }

    public function setDefaultOption(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => array('Default', 'Register')
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'front_user_registration';
    }
}
```

I tell sonata_user to use my form
**config.yml**

```
sonata_user:
    profile:
        register:
            form:
                type:               front_user_registration
                handler:            sonata.user.profile.form.handler.default
                name:               front_user_registration_form

fos_user:
    db_driver:      orm # can be orm or odm
    firewall_name:  main

    # if you change the class configuration, please also alter the sonata_user.yml file
    user_class:     Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User

    group:
        group_class:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager

    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager
    registration:
        form:
            type: front_user_registration
    profile:
        form:
            type:               fos_user_profile
            handler:            fos_user.profile.form.handler.default
            name:               fos_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Authentication]
```

which I declare as a service
**services.yml**

```
user.form.register.type:
        class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegisterType
        parent: fos_user.registration.form.type
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: front_user_registration }
```

When I try to display the form, I get the following error :

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Handler\ProfileFormHandler::process() must
>   implement interface FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface, boolean given,
>   called in
>   /Users/sylv/Sites/generajobs/vendor/sonata-project/user-bundle/Controller/RegistrationFOSUser1Controller.php
>   on line 49 and defined

Same goes if I add

```
arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
```

into my services.yml configuration.

Am i missing something here ?

Comment: Try this. [http://stackoverflow.com/same_issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279497/sonatauserbundle-override-form-profile)  Here is override profile form. It looks the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately he's mostly overriding the profile form. For the registration form, he uses the same code as above, with the same declaration in the services.yml file, which leads me to the same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a pretty stupid mistake, I had to change my "handler" line in config.yml to

```
handler:            sonata.user.registration.form.handler.default
```

instead of sonata.user.profile.form.handler.default as I saw on several examples on S.O.

The two handlers process() function do not except the same parameters.